# Creating a new column sequence based on another column within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe `Outfall` which has a sequence in the column `['Head']`. The goal is to then make another column relative to `['Head']` called `['OHead']` which starts a new sequence once a certain value is matched. I dont have any issues applying a lamda function to create the new column `['OHead']` based on a conditional but am getting tied up on then initiating a new sequence with the same step size as `['Head']`.

```
To = 1.34
Head = np.linspace(0,4,49)
Outfall = pd.DataFrame(Head, columns=['Head'])
Outfall['OHead'] = Outfall['Head'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x <= To else i * 0.83 for i in range(1))
```

The list comprehension within the lamda statement obviously doesn't work but was giving it a shot thinking this might be the best approach.

The expected result would be a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        Head         OHead
0   0.000000      0.000000
1   0.083333      0.000000
2   0.166667      0.000000
3   0.250000      0.000000
...n...      
15  1.250000      0.000000
16  1.333333      0.000000
17  1.416667      0.083333
18  1.500000      0.166667
19  1.583333      0.250000
20  1.666667      0.333333
21  1.750000      0.416667
...n...
```

Using ...n... as place holders for the rest of the dataframe.

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

```
data = Outfall[Outfall <= To].dropna().tail(1).reset_index(drop=True).at[0,'Head']
Outfall['Head'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x <= data else x - data)
```

or

```
data = Outfall[Outfall <= To].dropna().tail(1).reset_index(drop=True).at[0,'Head']
Outfall['OHead'] = np.where(Outfall['Head'] <= data, 0, Outfall['Head'] - data)
```

Comment: This works great but i'm not really sure what is going on here. What I understand from your solution is that you are creating a column `data` where `Outfall` is less than `To`, dropping the 0 values, resetting the index at index 0 on the `Head` column and subtracted that to get the new `OHead` values?

Comment: @rweber almost yes, but `data` is not a `column` it is a `float` that is greatest number in `Head` that is less than or equal to `To`, because I recognized that you subtract `1.333333` from every number and I tried to find it.

Comment: Realizing now that there were lots of ways to go about this solution working directly with the values opposed to creating a new sequence.